# Which level of permission and type of encryption could be used on a NAS to be secure but usable?

Tags: encryption, permissions, shared-hosting

I need to use a NAS to stock data (from personal git and other type of service).

7777 is very permissive but it seems that the 0640 actually in use is not enough to works correctly with the services.

Also, I would like to know if this NAS could be encrypted to improve its security.

This NAS is used for internal package mirror and git repository

model: FreeNAS

Comment: This is too broad. How can anyone give a meaningful anwer as to which access permission mask to set on the files without knowing how the NAS manages users and services, and which services are in use? You need to give much more specific information about the NAS you're using.

Comment: You are right Pascal, I bring some more informations

Comment: @Pascal do you need something more?

Comment: Yes, this is still way too broad. If this NAS is a commercial product, you need to provide us with the exact model so people who have experience with it can answer your question. If you built it yourself, you need to explain whether the services you are using run under their own user and group ids, which os you're using (to determine what kind of encryption is supported) and so on.

Comment: Model of NAS added

Comment: Each service should be looked at separately to determine the least required permissions for the given service. What services are you trying to use? Who are the users and groups on this device? As a general rule, there are very few reasons to set permissions to 777.

Comment: As for encryption, I believe FreeNAS has native support for volume encryption. A simple Google search should return many tutorials on how to accomplish that.

Comment: @Nstr10 There is lot of information, but it is difficult to find "The" right way to do it correctly.

Comment: http://doc.freenas.org/9.3/freenas_storage.html#encryption
This seems fairly clear to me. Do you have specific questions about it?
You will never get a satisfactory answer if you aren't specific with your questions.